# How Can I Collect Pool Operator Submit APIs?

Tags: stake-pool, python, cardano-submit-api

Submit apis are possible given the current state of the chain, however, where can I go to verify that a submit API is genuine? The ideal solution would be a way to check stake pools for the API that can be automated.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "submit API"? Do you mean the transaction submission API? If so. I can't think of any way to verify that they are genuine. Worst case, for a non-genuine one, is that your transaction will not be submitted. The person running the transaction submission API cannot steal your funds because they do not have the private key that signed the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no such way to do that.

Anyone running `cardano-node` can also run `cardano-submit-api` and expose it for you to send transactions. This means that not only SPOs can do it, so I guess it is not possible to verify if the service is legit or not.